# Icon is not working in flutter awesome notification(NotificationActionButton)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android, flutter-local-notification, awesome-notifications

I am trying to add icon in flutter awesome notification(NotificationActionButton) but the icon is not appearing with button when the notification comes.

[image]

This is how I have stored the icon inside android/app/src/main/res/drawable and accessing it but when the notification comes it doesn't work.

After the **MARK DONE** it should be appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your device you use custom notification shade(like "miui" notification shade in mi phone)

you change that notification shade to "Android"

than it shows perfectly

settings -> Notification & control center -> Notification shade ->"Android"

Comment: I am not able to find settings -> Notification & control center -> Notification shade ->"Android" in my device , probably because it is stock android not miui or others.